# Return anything but a space with INSTR or CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, db2

I need to return results where a space is **NOT** used in the 3rd to last position (so from the right). Attempting to identify records where a US state acronym was not used.

```
JOHN MN    
MATT HI
TERRY ARKANSAS
```

I'm running this through `DBVisualizer` and I am stumped. I've tried to add some `CHARINDEX`, `RIGHT`...etc, but no combination is working.

Ideally, it would look something like:

```
SELECT INSTR(COLUMN, **<>** ' ', -3) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: IBM DB2 - I believe is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this :

```
select * from yourtable
where
case when length(trim(yourcolumn))>2 and right(trim(yourcolumn), 3) like ' %' then 1 else 0 end =0
```

or this

```
select * from yourtable
where trim(yourcolumn) not like '% __'
```

Comment: The 2nd one is so far the most workable query. Can you help me understand what this '% __' is doing? Is it basically check for any two characters following a space? Genius. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT IIF(len(RIGHT(COLUMN,LEN(COLUMN)-3))=LEN(REPLACE(RIGHT(COLUMN,LEN(COLUMN)-3),' ','')),0,1)
```

If it returns **0**, that means it does not have a blank value from 3rd to the last position.
If it returns **1**, that means it *does* have a blank.